# current_date doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Tchê,

eu to querendo trazer as informações do banco somente quando tiver o dia igual ao de hoje eu tentei dessas maneiras:

```
 ...
 ->where('a.data_hora = ?', current_date());
 ....
 ->where('a.data_hora = current_date');
 .....
 $data = date("Y-m-d");
 ->where('a.data_hora = ? ', $data);
 .. 
 ->where('a.data = data');
```

só que nenhuma me trouxe o resultado ....
o campo que eu quero trazer é um timestamp, mas não eu preciso só da data desse cara.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu consegui desta forma:

```
 ->where(' date(a.data_hora) = current_date ');
```

por causa do meu campo que é timestamp, eu tenho que passar para dizendo que eu só quero a data, no caso do date().

Answer (score 0):

Use a classe `\DateTime` para gerar uma data atual:

```
->where('a.data_hora = ?', new \DateTime('now')); // ou simplesmente new \DateTime()
```

Você ainda pode especificar o time zone, caso a aplicação esteja em um time zone e o banco em outro:

```
->where('a.data_hora = ?', new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));
```

Comment: mas com datetime ele não irá procurar informações sobre data e hora ?